# vertical space is different between subfigures

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I'm trying to add groups of subfigures like below, and LaTex is following.
However, the second captions starts little below than others.
How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/a_1.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/a_2.png}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/b_1.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/b_2.png}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/c_1.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/c_2.png}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/a_3.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/a_4.png}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/b_3.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/b_4.png}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/c_3.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.16\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/c_4.png}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\linewidth}
\small \textbf{Easy} [no duplicate]\\
\scriptsize
blah1\\
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\linewidth}
\small \textbf{Middle} [two duplicate]\\
\scriptsize
blah2\\
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\linewidth}
\small \textbf{Hard} [three duplicate]\\
\scriptsize
blah3
\end{subfigure}
\caption{sample1}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample1]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making your code minimally compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick fix of the issue you've encountered, you could change the final 3 instances of `\begin{subfigure}[b]` to `\begin{subfigure}[t]`. Better still, just omit the `\\` (double backslash) directives after `blah1` and `blah2`: They're not needed, and they're messing up the vertical positioning of these `subfigure` enviroments.

That said, you may want to rethink your entire approach to using `subfigure` environments. Since you're not using `\caption` directives with any of the 12+3= 15 `subfigure` environments, you could -- actually, should! -- replace all `subfigure` environments with `minipage` environments. In case you didn't know: a `subfigure` environment is nothing but a `minipage` environment that's been told what to do if it encounters a `\caption` directive. Since there are no such `\caption` directives, why incur the overhead?

Next, why even employ `minipage` environments to encase the 12 image files? It seems pointless to do so, as `\includegraphics` lets you state the (relative) dimensions of the images directly.

Finally, since you have 12 `\includegraphics` statements, it's a good idea to create a shortcut macro to automate the sizing of the images.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
%% Handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand\inc[1]{\includegraphics%
   [width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
%% First row of images:
\inc{figure/a_1.png}\hspace{0.005\linewidth}
\inc{figure/a_2.png}\hspace{\fill}
\inc{figure/b_1.png}\hspace{0.005\linewidth}
\inc{figure/b_2.png}\hspace{\fill}
\inc{figure/c_1.png}\hspace{0.005\linewidth}
\inc{figure/c_2.png}

\smallskip
%% Second row of images:
\inc{figure/a_3.png}\hspace{0.005\linewidth}
\inc{figure/a_4.png}\hspace{\fill}
\inc{figure/b_3.png}\hspace{0.005\linewidth}
\inc{figure/b_4.png}\hspace{\fill}
\inc{figure/c_3.png}\hspace{0.005\linewidth}
\inc{figure/c_4.png}

\smallskip
% Row of captions
\begin{minipage}{.305\linewidth}  % 0.305=2*0.15+0.005
\small\textbf{Easy} [no duplicate]

\scriptsize blah1
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{.305\linewidth}
\small\textbf{Middle} [two duplicate]

\scriptsize blah2
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{.305\linewidth}
\small\textbf{Hard} [three duplicate]

\scriptsize blah3
\end{minipage}

\caption{sample1}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would use captions in `subfigure` environments and in one `subfigure` merge four your images:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/a_1.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/a_2.png}

\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/a_3.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/a_4.png}
    \caption{\textbf{Easy} [no duplicate]\newline\scriptsize
             blah1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/b_1.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/b_2.png}

\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/b_3.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/b_4.png}
    \caption{\textbf{Middle} [two duplicate]\newline\scriptsize
             blah1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/c_1.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/c_2.png}

\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/c_3.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{figure/c_4.png}
    \caption{\textbf{Hard} [three duplicate]\newline\scriptsize
             blah1}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{sample1}
  \label{fig:3}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico, you are right. corrected! thank you very much!